# Friendly URL in php? With other pages readmore in htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

I have 2 pages in selecting data from mysql. First page - readmore.php, to get posts with `url` from table posts. Second page - categories.php to get data with `caturl` from table categories.

readmore.php in .htaccess

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+).html$ readmore.php?url=$1
    RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+).html/$ readmore.php?url=$1
```

categories.php in .htaccess

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+).html$ categories.php?caturl=$1
    RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+).html/$ categories.php?caturl=$1
```

My problem located when get caturl htaccess redirects me to readmore.php but I want redirect to categories.php

Comment: @Neograph734 i don't understand !! do you mean replace RewriteRule ^teaser_ to RewriteRule ^caturl_ or what ?? i get my url like that http://www.afrogfx.com/20121102103658-Beautiful-Island.html -> Domain.com/url

Comment: What @Neograph734 is saying is how are you going to differentiate whether the requested page goes to `readmore.php` or `categories.php`?

Comment: @Neograph734 Okay Thank You I Do It ;) respect

Comment: Sorry, I missed these comments. The answer is updated to help future people struggling with this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are redirecting *.html to a new url `readmore.php?url=*` therefor the url changes.
Since the url is now `readmore.php?url=*` the second set of rules won't fire (there is no longer a pattern that matches *.html).

Therefor categories will never be loaded. You will need to add a parameter in your url to distinguish the different types.

So make sure all your articles (or categories) have a common part in the url to indicate it is an page of that type.

**Example:**

```
RewriteRule ^article_([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+).html$ readmore.php?url=$1
RewriteRule ^cat_([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+).html$ categories.php?caturl=$1
```

So an article that was called `article_firstpost.html` would link to `readmore.php?url=firstpost` and `cat_cars.html` would link to `categories.php?caturl=cars`